# Constraining argument of interface method to a few allowed structs?

Tags: go, generics, methods

Suppose I have an interface :

```
type Module interface {
    Run(moduleInput x) error // x is the type of moduleInput
}
```

where each "module" will fulfill the `Run` function. However, the `moduleInput` isn't a single struct - it should be able to accept any struct but only allowed structs, i.e not `interface{}` (say, only `moduleAInputs` and `moduleBInputs` struct).

Ideally the `Run` function for each module would have the type of `moduleXInput` where X is an example module.

Is it possible to constrain the type of `moduleInput` with generics or otherwise?

Comment: also closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189810/how-to-use-a-type-parameter-in-an-interface-method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a generic interface, constrained to the union of the types you want to restrict:

```
// interface constraint
type Inputs interface {
    moduleAInputs | moduleBInputs
}

// parametrized interface
type Module[T Inputs] interface {
    Run(moduleInput T) error
}
```

Note that the interface `Module[T]` can now be implemented by types whose methods match the *instantiation of this interface*. For a comprehensive explanation of this, see: [How to implement generic interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72034479/how-to-implement-generic-interfaces)